# Pause the thread in AndEngine for specific time each loop

Tags: android, handler, andengine, wait, thread-sleep

I have one big problem. I need to create a method in AndEngine that will do following things:

1. cycle throigh stack with entities
2. get the number of the entity using getmNumber()
3. wait 1 second
4. using it's number swap between 2 sprites using setVisible();
5. wait 1 second
6. swap them back.
7. push the monster to another stack.

The problems are the numbers 3 and 5 when I need to wait 1 second each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* Do things */
        Thread.sleep(1000); /* Wait 1000 milliseconds */
        /* Do things */
    }
}).start();
```

And if you need to run something on ui thread, use this inside the thread

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* This will run on ui thread */
    }
});
```